# #1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'myuser'@'localhost' error while creating a user

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I am using Ubuntu 18.4 and due to several problems have reinstalled my XAMPP and after that my databases are remains safe but all my user accounts got deleted.
When I am trying to re create those accounts I am facing this issue.
And also I am getting another error

> The selected user was not found in the privilege table.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` as mysql roor user and then retry creating the user.

Comment: User is getting created but after that this error is coming "The selected user was not found in the privilege table."